# Error on filter in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am new to Python and this is my code:

```
  def f(n):
      return (n%2 != 0)


 def square (n):
      return (n*n)

 def applyif(list):
      filter(f, list)
      square(list)
      print(list)
```

User inputs a list, this list is being filtered with f(n) and then , if the filter applies , the odd elements in the list are squared.
Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
 applyif[1,2,3,4]
 TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

I would appreciate it , if someone could figure out , what I did wrong.

**EDIT**: 
Changed code to this:

```
def f(x):
   return (n%2 != 0)

def square (n):
    for i in n:
       n[i] = n[i]*n[i]
    return n

def applyif(lst):
   xyz = []
   xyz = filter(f,lst)
   print(xyz)
```

I am getting this error when I call

```
 applyif([1,2,3,4]) :


 <filter object at 0x028D2C30>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name your variable `list` and do `applyif([1,2,3,4])` instead of `applyif[1,2,3,4]`

```
def applyif(lst):
    filter(f, lst)
    square(lst)
    print(lst)

applyif([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: Ahh , ridiculous mistake , thank you very much sshashank124 !

Comment: @user2938633, No problem. We all make them once in a while :)

Answer (score 4):

You're calling it like this:

```
applyif[1,2,3,4]
```

This is a syntax error, you need to call it like:

```
applyif([1,2,3,4])
```

Additionally, you are computing the results of applying your two functions, and then throwing it away.  You need to rebind your variable to the returned result.

```
  li = filter(f, li)
  li = square(li)
```

(don't name local variables `list`)

You could further just write your function as

```
print list(map(square, filter(f, li))) # assuming python 3, drop the `list` call in py2
```

or

```
print [square(x) for x in li if filter(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use applyif([1,2,3,4]) instead of applyif[1,2,3,4] as suggested above. Additionally, you are going to run into trouble with your function square(n).

Square currently takes an integer and returns an integer. You are passing a list to it though. Consider changing your code as follows:

**edit:**

```
def f(x):
    return (x%2 != 0)

def square (n):
    for i in range(0,len(n)):
       n[i] = n[i]*n[i]
    return n

def applyif(lst):
    print(list(filter(f,square(lst))))
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just wanted to edit my question with this error. You prevented it , thanks

Comment: Just one question: What does "<filter object at 0x028D2C30>" mean , when I call   applyif([1,2,3,4]) ?

Comment: @user2938633, Cast filter object as list. Do this instead: print(list(lst))